# What the the numeric icon on my class means?

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation, icons

Recently I've noticed a numeric icon displayed with my class. What is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It symbolises a *numbered* **bookmark**. See [icon reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html#):
[image: IntelliJ bookmark symbols explained]

And for the case you need help on how to [manage and use bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#use_bookmarks).